# CSS Issue - Positioning

Tags: html, css

This code works fine on the latest browsers but not on Firefox 29. This is part of an ecommerce template page, and the issue I am running into is that the image shows up just once and out of place. When it works normally, the image repeats itself and is in the right place.

```
<style>
.standard-logo_container, .hoodie-logo_container {
    width: 61px !important;
    height: 62px !important;
    position: absolute !important;
    top: 48px !important;
    left: 84px !important;
}
.standard-logo_container img, .hoodie-logo_container img {
    width: 61px !important;
    height: 62px !important;
    border: none !important;
}
</style>
<td valign="top" class="ProductListImageCell" height="10" style="position:relative;;">
  <a href="[[DetailsURL]]">
    <div class="standard-logo_product-list">PleaseReplaceMe</div>
    <div class="hoodie-logo_product-list">PleaseReplaceMe</div>[[Thumbnail]]<br>
    <span class="ProductNameLink">[[ProductName]]</span><br>
  </a>
</td>
```

Comment: Can you show a code where we actually have a *thumbnail* or is this `[[Thumbnail]]` all you can give us? http://jsbin.com/kiroko/1/edit

Comment: What image? I see no image tag. I also see no correlation between your CSS and HTML nothing with the classes in the CSS. Also images in `img` tags don't repeat, background images do. Perhaps give us more context, what is renderd to the browser?

Comment: <img> is dynamically inserted into the applicable DIV.

[[Thumbnail]] is a token which populates the image dynamically.

Comment: As a TIP, you should not worry about previous versions of firefox at all. Forefox its always updating, and it will tell the user that there is an update available. If you try to control the css for each version of firefox, chrome, opera, IE, you will end with a huge css file, or too many css files and this is not for website optimization. You should stick with your latest browser version, specially on FireFox.

Comment: If you still need help with this, you should post the rendered html with the css as well.